# What is the recommended pattern for Firebase Storage offline access in React Native Expo?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-storage, expo

I’m building an app in React Native Expo where the user can take photos which will be uploaded to Firebase Storage for backup.

I’m trying to figure out the best way to do this so the user doesn’t have to re-download the images every single time they open the app.

So I need some sort of way to cache the images and I’d like to know what the preferred approach.

I was thinking of maybe just storing the images taken in AsyncStorage but then I would need to somehow implement synchronising it with Firebase cloud storage - so things like if new images for the user come in, I’d need to download it manually, delete it from firebase storage if they delete it from asyncStorage etc.

Is there a better solution to this?

Comment: As far as I know, no. For an app I'm currently working on I just implement it by saving everything in `AsyncStorage` and then uploading everything to Firebase. If uploading to Firebase fails the app keeps track of what failed to upload and attempts to upload it to Firebase the next time the user opens the app. In the meantime the user is still able to see the data because everything loads from `AsyncStorage`.